# How to return to json comment and its reply comment Nodejs?

Tags: mysql, node.js, json, api

I am doing comment and reply comment function in Nodejs
My table in database is include as [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1U2l.png)
This is my code show all comment and its reply

```
module.exports.viewCommentOfProduct = (req, res, next)=>{
    Comments.findAll({
        where: {
            productsid: req.params.id
        }
    })
    .then(comments=>{
        res.json({
            comments: comments
        })
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        res.json('Err: '+ err);
    })
}
```

However, it's not thing I need.
I want to respone to json as tree view

```
comment: [
 {
    id: 1
    usersid: 
    productsid:
    title:
    content: 
    reply: [
       {id:1, usersid:, title: , content:},
       {id:2, usersid:, title: , content:}
       .... and so on 
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to push all reply of comment when showing all comments.
Can you recommend for me how to solve this problem?

Comment: The Database image given has no coloumn called reply and what database are you using?  if it is MongoDb then u can try Aggrigation. If it is MYSQL u can try join and group.

Comment: I use self reference relationship in MYSQL so I don't need create another table replies. reply comment will reply parent via commentsid.